I can't adjust the brightness in Ubuntu 24.10 /// I put an new question!!! I hope you reply:)
I can't adjust the brightness in Ubuntu 24.10. Adjusting via the brightness slider or using the Fn+F3 or F4 keys doesn't work.
This is an HP Ryzen 5 laptop from HP. The brightness slider moves, but there is no change in screen brightness!

Did it work previously? With another version of Ubuntu?

You can try Brightness Controller, to control the brightness of the screen, save a color profile and load a profile from the saved list.
To install it, open a terminal and run in it:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brightness-controller
exit

Once installed, start Brightness Controller from the menu.
And by moving the vertical sliders up or down you should be able to adjust the brightness.
You can also install Pardus Night Light is a night light application based on redshift.
Open a terminal and run in it:
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://depo.pardus.org.tr/pardus/pool/main/p/pardus-night-light/pardus-night-light_0.2.0_all.deb
sudo apt install python3-gi python3:any gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 redshift
sudo apt install ~/Downloads/pardus-night-light_0.2.0_all.deb
exit

Once installed, start Pardus Night Light from the menu

Thank you for your answer, but the brightness controller doesn't work. (The second option doesn't seem to work either...) For your information, I'm a beginner who hasn't used the previous version, and I wonder if it's because it's too new to be stabilized, or if it's possible in the previous version. (Actually, besides the brightness, my bluetooth headset doesn't connect either, so I tried several methods, including Blue Man...)
I look forward to your answer... Thanks in advance:)
